# Склонение женской фамилии Пуджа

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли женская фамилия Пуджа ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склонение этой фамилии зависит от ударения и ее происхождения, но не зависит от того, мужская она или женская.

Если ударение падает на *у*, то склоняем по первому склонению: Пуджа — Пуджы , Пудже, Пуджу, Пуджой.

Если ударение падает на *а*, то склоняемость/несклоняемость зависит от происхождения этой фамилии. Если это славянская фамилия, как указано [здесь](http://onomastikon.ru/proishogdenie-familii-pudzha.htm), то она склоняется по первому склонению (см. выше).

[Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482)

> 13.1.11. Наиболее сложную картину представляют собой фамилии с конечным а. В отличие от предыдущих случаев, здесь существенное значение имеет, следует ли а после гласной или после согласной, падает ли на эту гласную ударение и (в определенных случаях) какого происхождения фамилия.
>
> Все фамилии, кончающиеся на а, которому предшествуют гласные (чаще всего у или и), несклоняемы: Галуа, Моруа, Делакруа, Моравиа, Эриа, Эредиа, Гулиа.
>
> Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное а после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению: Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т.д.; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание -а.
>
> Среди фамилий с ударным á после согласных есть как морфологически членимые, так и нечленимые, т. е. несклоняемые.
>
> Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения: Дюма, Тома, Дега, Люка, Ферма, Гамарра, Петипа и др.
>
> Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков) склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное окончание -а: Митта — Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой; сюда относятся: Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.

Причем не имеет значения, женская это фамилия или мужская:

> 13.1.8. Склонение фамилий, оканчивающихся в исходной форме на гласные, не зависит от того, мужские они или женские.
>
> Примечание. Материал Л. П. Калакуцкой показывает, что существует тенденция распространять соотношение, закономерное для фамилий на согласные, на фамилии с конечным а, т.е. склонять мужские фамилии, не склоняя женские. Редакторам следует всячески способствовать изживанию этой практики.